# Maven is not importing dependencies from local repository

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a spring/struts project in IntelliJ, the project is using dependencies from local repository (m2) and from maven repository

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>zkmaven</id>
            <name>ZK Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

When I run 'mvn clean install', I get the following errors :

```
Failure to find jscontrol:jscontrol:pom:1.1 in http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of zkmaven has elapsed or updates are forced

Failure to find org.zkoss.zk:zkplus:pom:6.5.2-SNAPSHOT in http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of zkmaven has elapsed or updates are forced

The POM for ZK:ZK-control:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
```

but when i check my local repository m2, i find that these dependencies exists.

I don't understand what's the problem here

Comment: Are you sure these files are in your local repository? Sometimes people mistake files ending `lastupdated` for the real files.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I checked the .m2 repository and I found the jar files

Comment: Are there are no files ending with `lastUpdated` in the folder?

Comment: there's those files yes, and there's jar file

Comment: You need to delete all lastUpdated files.

Comment: I did and i got this error :
Downloading from zkmaven: http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2/jscontrol/jscontrol/1.1/jscontrol-1.1.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/jscontrol/jscontrol/1.1/jscontrol-1.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for jscontrol:jscontrol:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for jscontrol:jscontrol:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: It seems like maven is always looking for dependencies in maven repository

Comment: No, Maven is not doing that. First of all, I would check whether the POM of `jscontrol:jscontrol:jar:1.1` is indeed missing in your local repository. Secondly, I forgot to mention that for offline builds, you should add the parameter `-o`.